# Drools can't compile rules when I try to run my program from SBT

Tags: sbt, drools

I'm new to Drools; I'm trying to learn Drools by examples but it seems that something is wrong with my settings, because I can't run my app successfully.

Here is my rule:

```
package com.example.rules

import newexample.Person;

rule "Is of valid age"

    when
        $p : Person( age < 18 )
    then
        $p.setValid( false );
end
```

And setting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
    <kbase name="rules" packages="rules">
        <ksession name="ksession-rule"/>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

When I try to run my application I get this error:

```
... - Adding Service org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl

... - Adding Service org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl

...  - Found kmodule: file:/.../poc-drools/target/scala-2.12/test-classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml
... - KieModule URL type=file url=/.../poc-drools/target/scala-2.12/test-classes
... - Unable to find pom.properties in /.../poc-drools/target/scala-2.12/test-classes
... - As folder project tried to fall back to pom.xml, but could not find one
... - Unable to load pom.properties from/.../poc-drools/target/scala-2.12/test-classes
... - Cannot find maven pom properties for this project. Using the container's default ReleaseId
... - Discovered classpath module org.default:artifact:1.0.0
... - KieModule was added: FileKieModule[releaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0,file=/.../poc-drools/target/scala-2.12/test-classes]
... - File 'rules/1th.drl' is in folder 'rules' but declares package 'com.example.rules'. It is advised to have a correspondance between package and folder names.
... - Unable to build KieBaseModel:defaultKieBase
Rule Compilation error : [Rule name='Is of valid age']
    com/example/rules/Rule_Is_of_valid_age734850681.java (1:0) : The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    com/example/rules/Rule_Is_of_valid_age734850681.java (1:0) : The type java.io.Serializable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    com/example/rules/Rule_Is_of_valid_age734850681.java (3:136) : Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
    com/example/rules/Rule_Is_of_valid_age734850681.java (6:369) : java.lang.Exception cannot be resolved to a type
```

I'm using Scala 2.13, SBT 1.2.6, JVM 1.8, & MacOS
I've installed JVM with `sdkamn`.
When I init project with Maven everything works find! but with sbt I get mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when my application that contains `Drools` is running in the same `JVM` process as `SBT`, it encounter issues with available classes and classpaths!
I didn't figure out the real reason, but when I config my project to run the application in separate JVM process, it worked:

```
fork := true
```